# How to insert substring into main string in perticular index in CPP?

Tags: c++, string, insert

I want to insert the substring into the main string after sorting the main string. How can I do that??

Like,

`ilovecoding` after sorting `cdegiilnoov`. And after that let say substring `eco`, it should be inserted as `decogiilnov`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int tc;
string s,a;
cin>>tc;

while(tc--){
    cin>>s>>a;
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout<<s<<endl;


}

return 0;
}
```

I got stuck here, also tried many times, till here I think everything is correct...

Comment: Please show the code where u tried to insert and remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is desired output or not, but you can check this function(include string header):

```
string process(string& main,string& sub){
  for (int i = 0; i < sub.size() ; i++){
      size_t pos = main.find(sub[i]);
      main.erase(pos,1);
  }
main.insert(1,sub);
return main;
}
```

and check here: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)